# Persistent 'Updating failed, invalid JSON response.' Error in WordPress Editor

Tags: errors, json

I'm facing some challenges while using any WordPress editor to make changes to my website. Initially, I encountered this issue with the Elementor editor, and as a troubleshooting step, I switched to the default editor. However, the problem persists.

Whenever I attempt to update a post or page, I'm confronted with the frustrating error message that reads, "Updating failed, invalid JSON response." Despite my efforts to resolve the issue, including logging out and back in, clearing my browser cache, and experimenting with different browsers, the problem remains unresolved. This ongoing obstacle significantly hampers my ability to perform essential updates and modifications on the website.

Curiously, the problem persists even after reuploading the website to the server. I'm reaching out to seek your assistance and expertise in identifying the root cause of this issue. Have any of you encountered a similar problem or have any insights into what could be causing this persistent error?

Any suggestions, advice, or potential solutions you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: Solution Found**
The problem was caused by the web application firewall and once I disabled it the problem went away. Thank you to all who helped.

Comment: I guess you have error in REST response of WP. Can you share console output of error, as well as XHR response for request that shows error?

Comment: XHRPOST https://website name[HTTP/2 403 Forbidden 6854ms]


Image link to XHR response and request: https://ibb.co/F7WSXM6

Comment: Obviously, you have some problem with server REST response. It may be a lot of things. Try disabling all plugins and see if it still appears. Could you also share response string, not header response, but actual response of the request?

Comment: Check your site's error log, and see if there are entries logged when accessing REST endpoints.

Comment: The Response is an error 403 with supporting text such as proudly powered by our web server. I assume that our server is the issue